# What values should be in appsetting.json?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In the modern .net application there is a default config file - `appsettings.json`.
From the best practices, what values should I put in this file?

From my understanding, I should keep something that is commonly used by any environment in the system. Am I correct here?

For example, I have a *dummy* config key that has different values in each of my environments.
I define the value for this key in `appsetting.Development.json`, `appsetting.Production.json`, etc. What is the best option for `appsetting.json` in this case - *omit it* or *provide a fallback value* or *keep empty*?

Answer (score 2):

**I believe this page answers your question quite well:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

**From the page above:**

The default JsonConfigurationProvider loads configuration in the following order:

1. appsettings.json
2. appsettings.{Environment}.json

For example, the appsettings.Production.json and appsettings.Development.json files. The environment version of the file is loaded based on the IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName.

appsettings.{Environment}.json values override keys in appsettings.json.

Comment: My question is about what values should be exactly in appsetting.json file. Like something that should be reusable by each environment?